# How to find out userIds of users Passed thorough a workflow

Tags: liferay

Hi I am using kaleo workflow  and Liferay version 6.2.
How to find out userIds of users Passed thorough a workflow  .
What tables are effected when a transaction takes place in workflow

Answer (score 0):

Check this method:

```
com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowLogManagerUtil#getWorkflowLogsByWorkflowInstance(long companyId, long workflowInstanceId, List<Integer> logTypes, int start, int end, OrderByComparator orderByComparator)
```

It seems that each workflow log should have the information you need but I've never used it myself.